# Append parameter to nested array from Obervable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

Using RxJs Observable mid-stream has the following format:

```
{
    term: 'one',
    sources: [
        {
        name: 'google'
        },
        {
        name: 'yahoo'
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm looking to turn it into the format:

```
{
    sources: [
        {
        name: 'google',
        id: 'one'
        },
        {
        name: 'yahoo',
        id: 'one'
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'd like to append the term onto each element in the sources array.
Finally I'd really like the correctly formatted array elements emitted on their on.
I'm guessing it's something to do with mergeMap to emit a event for each array el but am struggling!.

RxJs v5.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct you can use mergeMap/flatMap to achieve this. 
Then use .from() to emit each source one at a time.

```
let data = {
    term: 'one',
    sources: [
        {
            name: 'google'
        },
        {
            name: 'yahoo'
        }
    ]
};

let obs$ = Observable.of(data) // mimicking whatever your observable sequence is
    .flatMap(res => {
        // assign id to each item in sources array
        res.sources.forEach(item => {
            item.id = res.term;
        });

        return Observable.from(res.sources);
    });

obs$.subscribe(res => {
    console.log('subscribe result', res);
});

// output is
// subscribe result {name: 'google', id: 'one'}
// subscribe result {name: 'yahoo', id: 'one}
```

Comment: Great stuff-thank you!

Just had to change flatMap to mergeMap because of the version of RxJs 
but worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concatMap` to convert the flatten the `Observable` and `map` to create a new Observable with `name` and `term` as property key.

```js
var dataLists = Rx.Observable.from([{
    term: 'one',
    sources: [
        {
        name: 'google'
        },
        {
        name: 'yahoo'
        }
    ]
}]);


dataLists = dataLists.concatMap(function(dataList) {
  return dataList.sources.map(function(source){
    source.term = dataList.term;
    return source;
  })
});

dataLists.forEach(function(dataList){
  console.log(dataList);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```